# how to extends class in hibernate which refer to a row in the same table by hbm mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, extends, polymorphism

I have a class `ActivityLink` which extends from `Activity`. `ActivityLink` has a property as `private Activity link;` i don't want touch table `Activity` but i want create second table as `ActivityLink` . I use Java 1.7 and latest version of hibernate.

**How can i realize it in hibernate by xml mapping?**

```
public class ActivityLink extends Activity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Activity link;

    public ActivityLink( Activity link ){  this.link = link; }

    //    getter en setter
}

public class Activity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String identity;
    public Character precision;
    public Date requestedTime;
    public Date effectiveTime;
    public String performerId;
    public Date schedulerTime;
    public Double fractionQty;
    public Short UserId;
    public Double totalVolume;
    public Double restVolume;

    public Activity() {    }

//    getter en setter
    }
```

**Activity.hbm.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">
    <class name="de.j2ee.order.ActivityLink"
           table="order_db..ActivityLink">
    <composite-id class="de.j2ee.order.PK" name="pk">
      <key-property name="identity" column="Identity_" access="field"/>
    </composite-id>
    <version name="version" column="Version_" access="field" type="java.lang.Long"/>
    <property name="identity" column="Identity_" update="false" insert="false"/>
    <property name="precision" column="Precision_"/>
    <property name="requestedTime" column="RequestedTime_"/>
    <property name="effectiveTime" column="EffectiveTime_"/>
    <property name="performerId" column="PerformerId_"/>
    <property name="schedulerTime" column="SchedulerTime_"/>
    <property name="fractionQty" column="FractionQty_"/>
    <property name="userId" column="UserId_"/>
    <property name="totalVolume" column="TotalVolume_"/>
    <property name="restVolume" column="RestVolume_"/>

    <union-subclass name="de.j2ee.order.ActivityLink" table="order_db..Activity">
          <property name="link"  />
    </union-subclass>-->

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a single table for `Activity` and `ActivityLink` then you have to use Table Per Class hierarchy strategy. Follow below link for details:

[10.1.1. Table per class hierarchy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html#inheritance-tableperclass)

So your mapping should look something like this:

```
<class name="Activity" table="Activity">
    <id name="identity" column="Identity">
    </id>
    <discriminator column="ACTIVITY_TYPE" type="string"/>
    <subclass name="ActivityLink" discriminator-value="Activity_Link">
        ...
    </subclass>
</class>
```

**Update:**

If you want to create a table for the sub-class `ActivityLink` then you need to use the below strategy:

[10.1.2. Table per subclass](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass)

For example:

```
<class name="Activity" table="Activity">
    <id name="identity" column="Identity">
    </id>
    <joined-subclass name="ActivityLink" table="Activity_Link">
        <key column="Activity_ID"/>
        ...
    </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

Comment: I changed mind because of some limitation of existing table `Activity`. I don't want touch table Activity but i want create second table as ActivityLink.

Comment: @michdraftlord, you have to use table for subclass approach in that case, see my updated answer.

Comment: How should my `ActivityLink.hbm.xml` look like?